# How to log output of first command and then execute next command in PHP?

Tags: php, shell, yii, console, command

I have command from where I am executing the PHP function and writing output to a log file and after success of this I want to run next command which should send email about the status of first command.

e.g.

```
$nextCommand = 'php _protected/yii xyz-integration/job-status-email ' . $processId . ' >'.realpath(Yii::$app->basePath) . '/../../uploads/second_log.log 2>&1 & echo $!';
$command = 'php _protected/yii xyz-integration ' . $processId . ' >'.realpath(Yii::$app->basePath) . '/../../uploads/first_log.log 2>&1 & echo $! && '.$nextCommand;
exec($command, $output);
```

By doing this I am able to echo output of the **php _protected/yii xyz-integration ' . $processId . '** to the **realpath(Yii::$app->basePath) . '/../../uploads/first_log.log**.

But **after** running this process I want to send an email about the status of first command. Right now I am getting status as **In-Progress**  which means **$nextCommand** is not getting executing after first finishes the execution(Here in my case I want status which should be like success or failed which is been updated in database by first command). If I remove the & echo $! then It won't log the output/error to the log file which is necessary.

Comment: create a function and call that function, In that function run the first cmd then depending on the status of first cmd output , run the second.

Comment: Like so `fun1 () { echo 1; }; fun2 () { echo 2; }; fun1 && fun2` Function `fun2` will run only if function `fun1` succeed.

Comment: 2>&1 & echo  here according to my knowledge '&' separate's the two commands. So output of first command is being written to given path

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a code change that I made to solve the issue.

```
$nextCommand = 'php _protected/yii xyz-integration/job-status-email ' . $processId . ' >'.realpath(Yii::$app->basePath) . '/../../uploads/second_log.log 2>&1 & echo $!';
$command = 'php _protected/yii xyz-integration ' . $processId . ' >'.realpath(Yii::$app->basePath) . '/../../uploads/first_log.log 2>&1 ';
exec($command .' ; '. $nextCommand);
```

For readability purpose I have assigned commands to variables and using **';'** I have executed the both commands one after the other.

Answer (score 0):

This code segment `2>&1 & echo $! &&` should be `2>&1 && echo $! &&` (look at the missing `&` character after `&1`.

The reason is with only one `&` character in the end, the command will run in the background and return immediately. So that your second command is started when the first command is not finished yet.

Comment: Doing this I couldn't get the error(that I have created purposely) in the first_log.log file.